# React, append some file to the source code only 1 time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to append to the body some js script when a React Component render, but only 1 time.

Currently I have this code:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '//some/path/file.js';
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  // some code, no useEffect, hooks, etc, until now.
  return( // etc);
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I can see in the source code that the file is well appened, but more than 1, because I guees that it will be appened each time that the component renders.

How can I append only one time?
Should I search on the source if it's already append, and if it's not, append it? but how

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use useLayoutEffect:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//path/file.js';
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  return (
```

It seems that it is working